# youtube-dl is not working

Tags: command-line, youtube

I am using youtube-dl to download some videos from youtube. But when I write:

```
youtube-dl http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn_YodiJO6k
```

I get:

```
[youtube] Setting language
[youtube] rn_YodiJO6k: Downloading video webpage
[youtube] rn_YodiJO6k: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] rn_YodiJO6k: Extracting video information

ERROR: unable to download video
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to watch that video? I can't access it from my country.

Comment: When I press this link Is shows it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rn_YodiJO6k

Comment: Is it a problem with this particular video, or with others as well?

Comment: All the videos I have tried

Comment: This is actually a bug, and I entered a launchpad bug *https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/youtube-dl/+bug/1128610)  that refers to the upstream fix.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49308/youtube-dl-stoped-working-debian) was asked on unix.stackexchange.com.

Youtube changed something to make it incompatible with `youtube-dl`, it's been fixed in the latest version. Use the following to update `youtube-dl` until the package system gets the updated version:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

#### Update

As noted by *sup* in the comments `youtube-dl` is patched in Ubuntu to disable the `--update` option because of security concerns ([the bugreport is here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/youtube-dl/+bug/1063469)). It is also argued in the bugreport that `youtube-dl` is a moving target, so the version in the repositories is often out of date. This makes easy upgrade a necessity.

Easy upgrade is still possible with e.g. `pip`. Install like this (you may want to uninstall old versions of `youtube-dl` first):

```
sudo pip install youtube_dl
```

Upgrading can now be done with:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade youtube_dl
```

As documented on the [youtube-dl download page](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html). Note that similar security concerns are attached to this method as well.

Comment: This no longer work: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/youtube-dl/+bug/1063469

Install a new version from upstream:
`sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/2013.11.07/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`
`sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`
(info from here: http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html )

Comment: @sup: I have added a `pip` alternative which is almost as convenient.

Comment: Cool, only it already is disabled, I edit your answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 6):

For me the following lines worked:

```
sudo apt-get remove -y youtube-dl
wget -O - https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl > /dev/null
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
hash -r
```

Comment: Adding the pip install bin folder to the path could also help.

Answer (score -6):

You have to put double quotes (`"`) before and after the URL of the video to make it work.
I don't think it's a bug.

For example:

```
youtube-dl "<video-URL>"
```

Comment: This won't solve the issue.