# youtube-dl failed to extract signature

Tags: youtube-dl

It is considered very useful to utilize `youtube-dl` software for downloading youtubes.

A message is seen and it stopped working, which is following.

```
ERROR: Signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 479, in _decrypt_signature
    video_id, player_url, s
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 383, in _extract_signature_function
    res = self._parse_sig_js(code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 454, in _parse_sig_js
    u'Initial JS player signature function name')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 391, in _search_regex
    raise RegexNotFoundError(u'Unable to extract %s' % _name)
RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract Initial JS player signature function name; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output. Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update.
; please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output. Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update.
```

What should I do to proceed?

Comment: It clearly states in the message: "please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug" So why not do that?

Comment: `Make sure you are using the latest version; type  youtube-dl -U  to update.` Did you do that?

Comment: Dear David Foerster, I tried and got a message 'It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.'

Comment: @HELLOVENUS You're right `youtube-dl -U` doesn't work anymore. The instructions for updating youtube-dl to the latest version are at: [youtube-dl is not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194420/youtube-dl-is-not-working). btw it also works if you use `pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` instead of `pip install --upgrade youtube_dl` and it also works for a local install (i.e. without using sudo) done inside a Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You are getting this error:

```
Unable to extract Initial JS player signature function name
```

...because youtube-dl is not up-to-date. Google has been changing the way to access YouTube videos more frequently now than was the case a few years ago, so in order to keep youtube-dl up-to-date, it has to be updated more frequently too. To install the latest version of youtube-dl open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # start with snap run youtube-dl
```

or:

```
sudo apt remove youtube-dl  
sudo apt install python3-pip
python3 -m pip install youtube-dl
```

To upgrade youtube-dl to the latest version:

```
sudo snap install youtube-dl # youtube-dl snap is automatically upgraded
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

It's crazy how frequently Google has been changing the code for accessing videos on YouTube. I seem to have remembered updating youtube-dl only a couple of month's ago, but it still couldn't download the selected video until I updated it.

youtube-dl is a Python program, so you can also locally install the latest version of youtube-dl in a Python virtual environment. For information about how to setup and use a Python virtual environment see [How to set up and use a virtual python environment in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244641/how-to-set-up-and-use-a-virtual-python-environment-in-ubuntu).

Comment: Didn't work for me :-(

Comment: For me I had to uninstall first "sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl" and then use the command to install with pip

Answer (score 6):

The only way I was to get it working was the latest version (for me on debian) with

```
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
hash -r
```

from the [github repo](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#how-do-i-update-youtube-dl)

Answer (score 3):

It once happened to me. As they said on comments you must update your system or just youtube-dl. Also is good use quotes as follow in this example:

```
youtube-dl "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6AL-WpgoFw"
```

Comment: This character `¨` you used in your post is not visible. replace it with `'` or `"`.

Comment: worked for me ;)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this solved it

```
 sudo -H pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

and try to put the link into "`link`"

Comment: Worked with a little change: `sudo -H python3 -m pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Answer (score 1):

## Only this way is working for me!

When I trip every time I take the new music, and here is how to install youtube-dl from pip.

If you install it from repo, it cannot download the music, **always complains**!.
So use this to download spongebob relaxing masterpeace:

```
!pip install --upgrade youtube-dl 
!youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oq526_37wc0
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. I got this thing work by using the instruction given in the error:-

`sudo youtube-dl -U`

I don't know the exact reason for why this way of update worked and not that upgrade command..

Comment: `sudo youtube-dl -U` didn't work on Ubuntu 18.04. It gave these results: `sudo youtube-dl -U Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...] youtube-dl: error: youtube-dl's self-update mechanism is disabled on Debian. Please update youtube-dl using apt(8). See https://packages.debian.org/sid/youtube-dl for the latest packaged version.` however `sudo snap install youtube-dl-casept` did work on 18.04.