# Getting error while using Youtube-dl

Tags: youtube-dl

when I started downloading youtude-dl the following error is being displayed. What should I do?

```
wanderer@wanderer-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ youtube-dl -f '(mp4) [height<480]' -- zfaISdylg7c
[youtube] zfaISdylg7c: Downloading webpage
[youtube] zfaISdylg7c: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] zfaISdylg7c: Extracting video information
[youtube] zfaISdylg7c: Downloading js player en_US-vflV3n15C
ERROR: Signature extraction failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 1057, in _decrypt_signature
    video_id, player_url, s
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py", line 971, in _extract_signature_function
    errnote='Download of %s failed' % player_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 529, in _download_webpage
    res = self._download_webpage_handle(url_or_request, video_id, note, errnote, fatal, encoding=encoding, data=data, headers=headers, query=query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 436, in _download_webpage_handle
    urlh = self._request_webpage(url_or_request, video_id, note, errnote, fatal, data=data, headers=headers, query=query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/extractor/common.py", line 416, in _request_webpage
    return self._downloader.urlopen(url_or_request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py", line 2001, in urlopen
    return self._opener.open(req, timeout=self._socket_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 421, in open
    protocol = req.get_type()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 283, in get_type
    raise ValueError, "unknown url type: %s" % self.__original
ValueError: unknown url type: /yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflV3n15C/base.js
 (caused by ValueError(u'unknown url type: /yts/jsbin/player-en_US-vflV3n15C/base.js',)); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install youtube-dl?

Comment: Also, have you checked [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598200/youdtube-dl-failed-to-extract-signature) question's answer already?

Comment: This issue https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/pull/11892 Try it #pip install git+https://github.com/Khang-NT/youtube-dl.git

Comment: Version is 16.04.

Comment: This is the latest error I am getting when I try to update youtube-dl

Comment: The directory '/home/wanderer/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem even when I removed and reinstalled youtube-dl according to the above given fix. The solution came only when I run synaptic, found the package 'python' right-clicked on it and installed the recommended packages.