# erro I am getting pip youtube-dl

Tags: 14.04, youtube-dl

This is the error I am getting. What should I do?

```
The directory '/home/wanderer/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

wanderer@wanderer-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ ls -l ~/.cache
total 10896
drwx------ 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Jan 31 18:27 compizconfig-1
-rw-r--r-- 1 wanderer wanderer    20480 Dec 21 17:08 event-sound-cache.tdb.32d9967adb37400189d126e0f5a3027d.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
drwx------ 8 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 06:34 evolution
drwxr-xr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 17 07:52 fontconfig
drwxr-xr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Jan 26 09:08 gnome-calculator
drwxrwxr-x 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 06:35 gnome-software
drwx------ 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 20:11 google-chrome
drwxrwxr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Jan 31 18:27 gstreamer-1.0
drwxrwxr-x 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 06:34 ibus
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wanderer wanderer 10547304 Jan 31 09:56 icon-cache.kcache
drwxrwxr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 20 15:55 indicator-appmenu
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wanderer wanderer   474971 Jan 31 09:56 ksycoca5_en-IN_heSnpj7ybDg_HlxVjeY2lnFbClw=
drwxrwxr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Jan 31 18:28 logrotate
drwx------ 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 18:38 mozilla
drwxrwxr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Dec 19 07:06 pdfmod
drwxrwxr-x 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Dec 16 20:53 shotwell
drwx------ 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Dec 26 08:09 simple-scan
drwx------ 5 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 07:05 thumbnails
drwx------ 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Dec 19 20:29 thunderbird
drwxr-xr-x 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 13 19:47 totem
drwx------ 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 14 08:16 unity-control-center
drwxrwxr-x 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Jan 15 04:59 update-manager-core
drwx------ 2 wanderer wanderer    16384 Jan 31 20:42 upstart
drwx------ 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Dec 10 20:22 vlc
drwx------ 2 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 19 08:17 wallpaper
drwxrwxr-x 3 wanderer wanderer     4096 Nov 28 08:05 youtube-dl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 wanderer wanderer       11 Jan 25 07:09 zeitgeist-vacuum.stamp
wanderer@wanderer-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$
```

sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl

ok !!. What should I do?

Comment: Check ownership of `~/.cache` and or `~/.cache/pip` .

Comment: Explain please. I am new to Ubuntu

Comment: type this in terminal (to open terminal: `ctrl+alt+t`) `ls -l ~/.cache` then `ls -l ~/.cache/pip` and post the result.

Comment: Any luck with the terminal ?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/home/wanderer/.cache/pip': No such file or directory

Comment: What of the `~/.cache` dir?

Comment: also show the result of `ls -l ~/.cache | grep pip`.

Comment: Please remove them from comments and place them in your question.

Comment: what pip command are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [youdtube-dl failed to extract signature](http://askubuntu.com/questions/598200/youdtube-dl-failed-to-extract-signature)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I update youtube-dl?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/380438/how-can-i-update-youtube-dl)

Comment: @George I don't think it's a duplicate of the question linked to in your comment because it says in the question that he already tried `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` and also because the command `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl` sometimes doesn't work in some situations so an alternate way of updating youtube-dl is required.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sudo, if you are installing with `pip` then install to your home directory like so:

```
pip install --user youtube-dl
```

Uninstall which ever version you have now and run the above command as your regular user, and you won't have permissions problems any more. To update use:

```
pip install --upgrade --user youtube-dl
```